# can we get other's facebook page feeds via permanent access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have got facebook permanent **access_token**(which i received by creating a new app via my facebook account), can i use this token to fetch feeds from pages other than my own account. For example can i fetch public feeds from Coca Cola's Page via this access token ??
I am developing a web part for a company who maintains its own facebook page, now i want to get public feeds from that page to do this i need to pub permanent access_token that never expires. The Url which i am hitting on browser is like :
https://graph.facebook.com/ABCCompany/posts?&limit=50&access_token={permanent_access_token}

Waiting for your resonse :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, You can access other page feed by using extended access token via facebook app. Here is the e.g.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/CocaColaUnitedStates/posts?&limit=50&access_token=YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_EXTENDED_TOKEN

The json data will return on your browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Musakkhir, but as you can see it returns posts textual information not its link. how could i navigate a user to particular post  ?

Comment: From where we will get EXTENDED_ACCESS_TOKEN.?

Comment: What is the age of Extended_access_token.?

Comment: @V.J.: Go read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: Thanks.. @CBroe
I think its easy to use APPID|APPSECRET as a access token instead of this extended token.. M i right?

Comment: Depends on whether or not you have access to the data you want with an app access token. If the page you want data from is limited/restricted in any way (age, location, alcohol-related content) – then you won’t get anything with your app token, but need to use a page token or a user token (for a user that satisfies the requirements) instead.

Comment: Here is the url =>https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/ from which you will get access token, debug that access token and try to generate extended access token.